# Drop down menu display on image hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, drop-down-menu

I am implementing friends activity tab similar to Yahoo news as in this [link](http://in.news.yahoo.com/what-makes-iit-kanpur-india%E2%80%99s-best-engineering-college.html#prev) on my website. It shows what your friends are doing on my website!

Please connect with facebook to see the activity tab. However, I am unable to make a proper drop-down menu where I can display the products from my website.

Can anyone redirect me to some proper plugin for the same or give some other hints

Thanks !!

Comment: What *is* your question? What have you tried? Where do you need specific coding help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's plenty of examples of HTML drop down menus on the web. A quick Google search will give you something to work with. Here's one:

http://www.onextrapixel.com/2011/06/03/how-to-create-a-horizontal-dropdown-menu-with-html-css-and-jquery/

Fancy:

http://www.99points.info/2010/09/fancy-menus-using-jquery-and-css/

Comment: I posted for a fancy one , if available with anyone.

Comment: The second link has some cool ones